# How do I insert a custom struct into another struct that holds a 2 dimensional pointer of the initial struct?

Tags: c, shell, struct, command, malloc

I have two structs, one that creates a command. Another that holds a 2D pointer structure of those commands.

```
typedef struct SimpleCommand {
    // Available space for arguments currently preallocated
    int _numberOfAvailableArguments;
    // Number of arguments
    int _numberOfArguments;
    // Array of arguments
    char *_arguments[];
}SimpleCommand;
```

For example: 
Simple command 0: ls -la

Now I need to insert this command into the pointer inside of this struct so that would be in row 0 with type simple command.

```
typedef struct Command {
        int _numberOfAvailableSimpleCommands;
        int _numberOfSimpleCommands;
        SimpleCommand ** _simpleCommands;
        char * _outFile;
        char * _inputFile;
        char * _errFile;
        int _background;
        int outputAppend;
}Command;
```

Then, I will be able to construct a new Simple command, and insert it into row 1. Then I would have:
Command->simpleCommands[0] = simpleCommand 0
Command->simpleCommands[1] = simpleCommand 1

So far, I am able to create and verify the simple commands are working. Here is what I have attempted to do to insert a simple command into the commands->simplecommands pointer:

```
void insertSimpleCommand(SimpleCommand * simpleCommand, Command * command ){
    command->_simpleCommands = realloc(command->_simpleCommands, sizeof(simpleCommand)*3);
    SimpleCommand * tempCommand = simpleCommand;

    command->_simpleCommands[command->_numberOfSimpleCommands] = tempCommand;

    command->_numberOfSimpleCommands++; //increase the number of simple commands in the commands
}
```

What happens next when I am doing it this way is that the old command->simpleCommands[0] is being overwritten with the new simpleCommand. What can I do differently so that these simple commands are properly added one by one and all accessible thereafter?

**EDIT:**
Here is a minimum reproducible sample of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// Describes a simple command and arguments
typedef struct SimpleCommand {
    // Available space for arguments currently preallocated
    int _numberOfAvailableArguments;
    // Number of arguments
    int _numberOfArguments;
    // Array of arguments
    char *_arguments[];
}SimpleCommand;

// Describes a complete command with the multiple pipes if any
// and input/output redirection if any.
typedef struct Command {
        int _numberOfAvailableSimpleCommands;
        int _numberOfSimpleCommands;
        SimpleCommand ** _simpleCommands;
        char * _outFile;
        char * _inputFile;
        char * _errFile;
        int _background;
        int outputAppend;
}Command;

//FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
void insertSimpleCommand( SimpleCommand * simpleCommand, Command * command );
void insertArgument(SimpleCommand *command, char * argument );

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    //initialize the global currentsimplecommand struct
    SimpleCommand *_currentSimpleCommand = malloc(sizeof(*_currentSimpleCommand) + sizeof(char[50]));
    _currentSimpleCommand->_numberOfArguments = 0;
    _currentSimpleCommand->_numberOfAvailableArguments = 1;
    _currentSimpleCommand->_arguments[_currentSimpleCommand->_numberOfArguments] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 50);

    //SET UP COMMAND struct
    Command *_currentCommand = (Command*)malloc(2 * sizeof(Command));
    _currentCommand->_numberOfSimpleCommands = 0;
    _currentCommand->_background = 0;
    _currentCommand->outputAppend = 0;

    insertArgument(_currentSimpleCommand,"ls");
    insertArgument(_currentSimpleCommand,"-la");
    insertSimpleCommand(_currentSimpleCommand, _currentCommand);
    clear(_currentSimpleCommand);

    insertArgument(_currentSimpleCommand,"head");
    insertSimpleCommand(_currentSimpleCommand, _currentCommand);

    for (int i = 0; i < _currentCommand->_numberOfSimpleCommands; i++){
         printf("\n\nTEST: %d   %s\n\n", i, _currentCommand->_simpleCommands[i]->_arguments[0]);
    }
    /*
        THE OUTPUT OF THIS WILL PRODUCE THE SAME ARGUMENT[0] regardless fo the row we are on!
    */


} 

void insertSimpleCommand(SimpleCommand * simpleCommand, Command * command ){
    command->_simpleCommands = realloc(command->_simpleCommands, sizeof(simpleCommand)* command->_numberOfSimpleCommands);
    SimpleCommand * tempCommand = simpleCommand;
    command->_simpleCommands[command->_numberOfSimpleCommands] = tempCommand;
    command->_numberOfSimpleCommands++; //increase the number of simple commands in the commands
}

//insert argument into simple command
void insertArgument(SimpleCommand *command, char * argument ) {
    //allocate space for the new command
    command->_arguments[command->_numberOfArguments] = (char*)realloc(command->_arguments[command->_numberOfArguments], sizeof(char*) * strlen(argument));
    strcpy(command->_arguments[command->_numberOfArguments], argument);
    command->_arguments[command->_numberOfArguments+1] = NULL;
    command->_numberOfArguments++;
}

//clears the simple command for the next one
void clear(SimpleCommand *command){
    free(command);
    SimpleCommand *_currentSimpleCommand = malloc(sizeof(*_currentSimpleCommand) + sizeof(char[50]));
    _currentSimpleCommand->_numberOfArguments = 0;
    _currentSimpleCommand->_numberOfAvailableArguments = 1;
    _currentSimpleCommand->_arguments[_currentSimpleCommand->_numberOfArguments] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 50);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of multiplying by this magic number `*3`? Why not use `command->_numberOfSimpleCommands`

Comment: I could but that is not the issue here!

Comment: To allow us answer without just guessing, you want to show us at least how all variables involved are initialised, and how then the function is called . You also might like to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example As it stands the question is not answerable in a serious manner.

Comment: `SimpleCommand * tempCommand = simpleCommand;` does ***not*** create a copy of `simpleCommand`.

Comment: I added how I initialized them. @user3386109 how can I replicate the struct I have of a simple command into say Commands->simplecommands[0], then [1]?

Comment: You have to allocate memory for the structure, then allocate memory for the arguments array, then copy the fields of the structure, then make copies of all the argument strings and fill in the arguments array with the pointers to the copies. In other words, make a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) of the structure.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding, basically what I am doing here is setting the pointer in commands->simplecommands[x] to the address of the simple command, and that is why i am overwriting it after further modifying the simple command? Sorry this post has me very confused! @user3386109. Also, could I use something like memcpy() to copy the data?

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible example to the best of my ability above. @user3386109

Comment: The `clear` function frees the old `SimpleCommand` structure (probably a bad idea), and then allocates a new one. But the code doesn't do anything with the new structure. The `_currentSimpleCommand` in the function is not the same as the `_currentSimpleCommand` in `main`. So when the function returns, the new structure is lost forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct SimpleCommand {
    int id;
    // Available space for arguments currently preallocated
    int _numberOfAvailableArguments;
    // Number of arguments
    int _numberOfArguments;
    // Array of arguments
    char *_arguments[];
}SimpleCommand;

typedef struct Command {
        int _numberOfAvailableSimpleCommands;
        int _numberOfSimpleCommands;
        SimpleCommand ** _simpleCommands;
        char * _outFile;
        char * _inputFile;
        char * _errFile;
        int _background;
        int outputAppend;
}Command;

void insertSimpleCommand(SimpleCommand * simpleCommand, Command * command ){
    command->_simpleCommands = realloc(command->_simpleCommands, sizeof(SimpleCommand *) * command->_numberOfSimpleCommands + 1);

    SimpleCommand *newCommand = malloc(sizeof(SimpleCommand));
    memcpy(newCommand, simpleCommand, sizeof(SimpleCommand));

    command->_simpleCommands[command->_numberOfSimpleCommands] = newCommand;
    command->_numberOfSimpleCommands++; //increase the number of simple commands in the commands
}

void main() {

    SimpleCommand s1;
    Command c;

    c._simpleCommands = malloc(sizeof(SimpleCommand *)*1);

    s1.id = 1;

    insertSimpleCommand(&s1, &c);

    s1.id = 2;

    insertSimpleCommand(&s1, &c);

    exit(0);

}

(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7de: file simple.c, line 40.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/s 

Breakpoint 1, main () at simple.c:40
40          c._simpleCommands = malloc(sizeof(SimpleCommand *)*1);
(gdb) n
42          s1.id = 1;
(gdb) 
44          insertSimpleCommand(&s1, &c);
(gdb) 
46          s1.id = 2;
(gdb) 
48          insertSimpleCommand(&s1, &c);
(gdb) 
50          exit(0);
(gdb) p *c->_simpleCommands[0]
$1 = {id = 1, _numberOfAvailableArguments = 32767, _numberOfArguments = 0, _arguments = 0x555555756290}
(gdb) p *c->_simpleCommands[1]
$2 = {id = 2, _numberOfAvailableArguments = 32767, _numberOfArguments = 0, _arguments = 0x5555557562b0}
(gdb)
```

Comment: This looks like it would work. However, I need the simple commands to be able to grow dynamically. In your sample code, they are initialized to s1, s2. I need to be able to continuously create these throughout the program, and keep adding them to the commands ** simplecommands.

Comment: copy the whole code and do the steps I did with gdb.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check out my minimum reproducible example in the original post? @Gábor

Comment: Why did you use a single pointer for the SimpleCommand * _simpleCommands; rather than a pointer to a pointer? I need to store many of these simple commands.

Comment: you allocate memory for pointers and not for structs. please follow my code.

Comment: if keeping the SimpleCommand as ** is a requirement then you need to (1) malloc for every new element and realloc for pointers array (2) and insert the new pointer (1) to this array (2). That would make it more complicated and I don't see the benefit of it.

Comment: It is a requirement unfortunately, is it possible for you to give a very short example of this? I just do not understand inserting the pointer into the array. That is where I go wrong.